Looking for a children’s book where a kid makes a fake mainframe and hides inside with a typewriter answering questions
From the sixties I think? A series character I thought was Homer Price but isn't. The mainframe has a name similar to Univac. [edit: identified by Buzz as “One for the Computer” or “One for the UNIVAC” by Ethelyn Parkinson.

Just to be clear, was this a standalone book or part of a series?

I hate to harp on it, but what's the fantasy/sci-fi aspect of it?

Sounds more like Danny Dunn , Encyclopedia Brown or Henry Reed...

Both Homer Price and Henry Reed were illustrated by Robert McCloskey...

Danny Dunn and the Homework Machine involves such a mainframe but, as I recall it, it's legit, although the characters figure out that it's as much work to program it to do their homework as it is to just do the homework themselves.

This sounds like "One For the Computer" by Ethelyn M. Parkinson, which featured in the elementary school reading textbook Freedom's Ground.  The style is similar to a Homer Price story.  (In fact, Freedom's Ground also featured a Homer Price tale.)  Other than not having a "UNIVAC"-like name, this matches the question pretty well.  In particular, inside the large cardboard box that forms the "computer," five boys operate various mechanical devices—including, most importantly, the typewriter that produces the "computer's" answers to questions.

This is the right answer! There’s an illustration of the machine and Univac is scrawled across the top. This explains why I couldn’t find it on the ‘list of fictional computers” wiki page. Many thanks, Buzz.

Also, it seems that the original title was “One for the Univac,” which makes me wonder if the textbook publisher had some qualms about a copyright claim.
